# How long was the overland trip between St. Petersburg and Okhotsk?

Tags: russia, trade, travel

The Imperial supply chain for Russian America went over land through Okhotsk. Officials communicating with the various headquarters in St. Petersburg traveled there by way of Iakutsk and Irkutsk. For the transit of goods or persons, how long did this trip take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to De Lesseps (survivor of the La Perouse voyage), travel between Kamchatka and St. Petersburg took half a year in the late 18th century.